# Identify groups with all missing values for a variable and extrapolate within groups in R

Tags: r, filtering, grouping, extrapolation

I want to identify the groups that only have missing values for a given variable. My data looks like this:

```
id <- seq(1:4)
year <- c(2005, 2006, 2007, 2008)
y <- c(6, 11, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 9, NA, NA, 7, 8, 7, NA, 12)
test <- data.frame(id, year, y)
arrange(test, desc(id))
print(test)
```

I tried to group the data by id and created allNA variable that should separate groups that only have missing values (I need to preserve those rows untouched in the final result as well). Then I extrapolated within the groups that have some non-missing values:

```
test %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(allNA = !all(is.na(y))) %>%
  filter(allNA) %>%
  select(-allNA) %>%
  mutate(y2=na.spline(y))
```

I keep getting inconsistent results for my extrapolation. Sometimes after creating allNA variable, I can see some FALSE values and it leaves the year 2007's values as missing or drop them, but sometimes when I execute the code it is all TRUEs and it extrapolate everything. I wonder if the allNA variable is doing the job it is supposed to be doing. Because of that I decided to first identify the groups _ here year 2007 _ that just have NAs but I don't know how to do that and solve the extrapolation problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After creating the column `allNA`, use `if/else` to apply the `na.spline`

```
library(dplyr)
library(zoo)
test %>% 
    group_by(id) %>%
    mutate(allNA = all(is.na(y)),
            y2 = if(!allNA[1]) na.spline(y) else y)
```

Comment: Your code is extrapolating all the values _ including those for 2007 _ and doesn't leave NAs for that year. It seems it doesn't take the grouping into account and doesn't extrapolate within the groups.

Comment: @Marj the `mutate` is after the `group_by`

Comment: That's right but I have no clue why it's not working.

Comment: @Marj can you try with `dplyr::mutate(allNA = ..` in case you loaded `plyr` then the `plyr::mutate` masks the `dplyr::mutate`

Comment: I tried and it worked! Thanks! But another issue is that when I use the same code with "na.approx" function to interpolate, I get this error message:  
Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `y2`.
x Input `y2` can't be recycled to size 4.
i Input `y2` is `if (!allNA[1]) na.approx(y) else y`.
i Input `y2` must be size 4 or 1, not 2.
i The error occured in group 4: id = 4.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
Do you have any idea what might is causing this?

Comment: It is because it is removing NA values, you can use `na.approx(y, na.rm =FALSE)`

Comment: In the development versoin of zoo you don't have to check for NA's.  This works: `install.packages("zoo", repos="http://R-Forge.R-project.org"); 
test %>% 
group_by(id) %>%
mutate(y2 = na.spline(y, na.rm = FALSE))`